# Websockets in Adobe CQ5.5

Tags: websocket, aem

I am trying to set up websocket server in Adobe CQ5.5 (felix). I looked at a couple of java implementations like jwebsocket, but they seem to all need an appserver or atleast a servlet container to run on. I looked at the apache2 module, but its in C, I need a java implementation. Is there a solution that can easily integrate with CQ5.5? I can try and run Adobe CQ5.5 in glassfish or something, but that might be hard since we don't use glassfish and will need to get a license. Can I implement websockets in felix at all?

Answer (score 0):

CQ uses it's own web container by default within Felix, which I don't believe supports websockets.  However, you could deploy CQ into another container such as Jetty which supports web sockets.  Jetty is not however fully supported, falling into the [expected to work](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/technical_requirements.html) category (see SERVLET ENGINES / APPLICATION SERVERS section).

Alternatively, it *may* be possible to load a jetty into the felix OSGI container and have websockets offered over a port other than the ones used by CQ.